# Positioning a Sheet after using beginSheet:modalForWindow:?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nsapplication

I want to display a window as a sheet, which is perfectly running with the following code:

```
[NSApp beginSheet:mySheet
   modalForWindow:myWindow
    modalDelegate:nil 
   didEndSelector:NULL
      contextInfo:NULL];
```

However, there is ONE LITTLE PROBLEM:

- I'm using an implementation of [Chromium Tabs](https://github.com/rsms/chromium-tabs), and - for some reason probably related to the inner logic of Chromium Tabs - the sheet seems to appear somewhat LOWER than where I'd want it to be... (Perhaps that's what is considered as the window "border", but anyway...)

[image]

What's wrong? How could I fix that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just found it :

In the window's delegate, we implement `window:willPositionSheet:usingRect:` like this

```
- (NSRect)window:(NSWindow *)window willPositionSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet 
       usingRect:(NSRect)rect 
{
    rect.origin.y += 11;  // or as much as we need
    return rect;
}
```

Comment: I would also suggest submitting a bug report to the project owners. Otherwise, you might end up chasing magic numbers from one version of OS X (or Chromium Tabs) to the next as sizes and styles change.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi Good point, though in fact the version of Chromium Tabs I'm currently using is so heavily tweaked (by me) that if there is anyone I should notify, that would be me. :-)

Comment: Ah. That makes it harder to make a case. :-)

Comment: Having wasted hours trying to get`willPositionSheet` to work, you should note that this method should be in the parent window's delegate, not the sheet window's delegate.